# use list values as keys to dict with keys

Tags: python

I have a dictionary

```py
foo = {"/" : {"bar":"returnme"} }
```

and a list

```py
example  = ["/","bar"]
```

how do I use the list to return the value in "bar" ? (i.e. identical output to
`foo["/"]["bar"]` )

For clarity the value of the example list changes, the example could also be:

```py
foo = {"/" : {"bar": {"morefoo": {"returnme"}} }} 

example = ["/","bar","morefoo"]
```

foo[example]  --> "returnme"

For other functionality in the script I will need to be able to use the example list to add/remove things to the 'final' dictionary.

Comment: Ah, apologies- changed the error in the example

Comment: Generally, the expectation is that you will demonstrate an attempt and ask a specific question about an issue you are having.

Comment: I did attempt @Chris! my issue is I write in dutch, and have to translate my attempt to make it workable/easyer to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iteratively retrieve elements from a dictionary.

```py
def get(tree, keys):
    current = tree
    for key in keys:
        current = current[key]
    return current
```

and it works:

```py
>>> get({"/": {"bar": "returnme"}}, ["/", "bar"])
'returnme'
>>> get({"/": {"bar": {"morefoo": "returnme"}}}, ["/", "bar", "morefoo"])
'returnme'
>>>
```